# Why does the content of this inner div unexpetedly collapse to the left in firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser

I am trying to figure out why the inner div in [this web site](http://colinbarclay.com) will display properly with Safari and Chrome but goes awry in firefox. I have the code up on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/squigworm/Xfcdu/1/) here. I am fairly new to web-design so I may be missing something very obvious but I cannot seem to figure it out and have not been able to find a solution anywhere online yet. Any and all help is much appreciated.

Colin

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">

 <title>Code Example</title>

     <link href="_css/main_full.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
     <script src="_js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
     <script src="_js/gallery.js"></script> 

 </head>

 <body>

 <div class="page_container">          

        <div class="gallery_container">


<a href="sunlight.html" title="© C.M.B 2012"><img id="pos1" src="_images/galleryimages_full/sunlight_smallvector.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>

<a href="clownflat.html" title="© C.M.B 2012"><img id="pos2" src="_images/galleryimages_full/clownflat_smallvector.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>  

<a href="goldensun.html" title="© C.M.B 2012"><img id="pos3" src="_images/galleryimages_full/goldensun_smallvector.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>               

<a href="monstertheatre.html" title="© C.M.B 2012"><img id="pos4" src="_images/galleryimages_full/monstertheatre_smallvector.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>          

<a href="home.html" title="© C.M.B 2012"><img id="pos5" src="_images/galleryimages_full/home_smallvector.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B"></a>                 

<a href="wishingstar.html" title="© C.M.B 2012"><img id="pos6" src="_images/galleryimages_full/wishingstargallery_full.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>                 

<a href="cozycave.html" title="© C.M.B 2012"><img id="pos7" src="_images/galleryimages_full/cozycave_smallvector.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>                 

<a href="coffeetable.html" title="© C.M.B 2012"><img id="pos8" src="_images/galleryimages_full/coffeetable_smallvector.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>               

<a href="breakaway.html" title="© C.M.B 2012"><img id="pos9" src="_images/galleryimages_full/breakaway_smallvector.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>                 

<a href="happynappy.html" title="© C.M.B 2012"><img id="pos10" src="_images/galleryimages_full/happyns_smallvector.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>                 

<a href="boymeetsgirl.html" title="© C.M.B 2012"><img id="pos11" src="_images/galleryimages_full/boymeetsgirl_smallvector.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>                 

<a href="sadbaby.html" title="© C.M.B 2012"><img id="pos12" src="_images/galleryimages_full/sadbabygallery_full.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>                 

<a href="salvation.html" title="© C.M.B 2012"><img id="pos13" src="_images/galleryimages_full/salvation_smallvector.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>                 

<a href="orangestart.html" title="© C.M.B 2012"><img id="pos14" src="_images/galleryimages_full/orangestart_smallvector.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>                 

<a href="spaceobjects.html" title="© C.M.B 2012"><img id="pos15" src="_images/galleryimages_full/spaceobjectsgallery_full.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>                 

<a href="clown.html" title="© C.M.B 2012"><img id="pos16" src="_images/galleryimages_full/clown_smallvector.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>                 

<a href="ponycave.html" title="© C.M.B 2012"><img id="pos17" src="_images/galleryimages_full/ponycave_smallvector.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>                 

<a href="pacha.html" title="© C.M.B 2012"><img id="pos18" src="_images/galleryimages_full/pacha_smallvector.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>                 

<a href="goldstorm.html" title="© C.M.B 2012"><img id="pos19" src="_images/galleryimages_full/goldstorm_smallvector.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>                 

<a href="qero.html" title="© C.M.B 2012"><img id="pos20" src="_images/galleryimages_full/qerogallery_full.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>                 

<a href="bluesinmyheart.html" title="© C.M.B 2012"><img id="pos21" src="_images/galleryimages_full/theblues_smallvector.jpg" width="250" height="194" alt="© C.M.B 2012"></a>   


        </div>  

</div>   
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

/* Layout (global rules for fullsize) */

.page_container {
width: 1280px;
height: 3000px;
background-image: url(../_page_components/gallery/gallery_full.jpg);
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
/*position: relative;*/
/* padding-top: 19.541%; 248 pixels*/
}

.gallery_container 
{
width: 66.7%;  /* 853 pixels */
height: 55.3%; /* 1659 pixels */
/*margin: 19.541% auto 0% auto; - equal to 248px*/
padding: 19.5% 0 0 0;
margin: 0% auto 0% auto;
}


#pos1 {  /* Top Left Corner*/
padding-left: 0.3%;
padding-right: 4.91%;   
padding-bottom: 5.3%;
}

#pos2 {  /* Middle top row */
padding-left: 0.42%;    
padding-bottom: 5.3%;
}

#pos3 {  /* Topr Right Corner */
padding-left: 5.35%;
padding-bottom: 5.3%;
}

#pos4 {  /* The rest of the images/rows follow the same positioning pattern */
padding-left: 0.4%;
padding-right: 4.75%;   
padding-bottom: 5.3%;
}

#pos5 {
padding-left: 0.5%;
padding-bottom: 5.3%;
}

#pos6 {
padding-left: 5.15%;
padding-bottom: 5.3%;
padding-right: 0.2%;
}

#pos7 {
padding-left: 0.5%;
padding-right: 4.55%;   
padding-bottom: 5.3%;
}

#pos8 {
padding-left: 0.5%;
padding-bottom: 5.3%;
}

#pos9 {
padding-left: 5.25%;
padding-bottom: 5.3%;
 }

#pos10 {
padding-left: 0.5%;
padding-right: 4.55%;   
padding-bottom: 5.3%;
}

#pos11 {
padding-left: 0.5%;
padding-bottom: 5.3%;
}

#pos12 {
padding-left: 5.25%;
padding-bottom: 5.3%;
}

#pos13 {
padding-left: 0.5%;
padding-right: 4.55%;   
padding-bottom: 5.4%;
}

#pos14 {
padding-left: 0.5%;
padding-bottom: 5.4%;
}

#pos15 {
padding-left: 5.25%;
padding-bottom: 5.4%;
}

#pos16 {
padding-left: 0.5%;
padding-right: 4.55%;   
padding-bottom: 5.6%;
}

#pos17 {
padding-left: 0.5%;
padding-bottom: 5.6%;
}

#pos18 {
padding-left: 5.25%;
padding-bottom: 5.6%;
}

#pos19 {
padding-left: 0.5%;
padding-right: 4.55%;   

}

#pos20 {
padding-left: 0.5%;

}

#pos21 {
padding-left: 5.25%;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Fix

Set `.gallery_container img { display: inline-block;}` to fix it. [See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xfcdu/4/).

### Why

Apparently Firefox is not necessarily treating the `img` as that `display` setting to begin with, whereas the other browsers apparently are. Note that I did not actually see the issue in Firefox 17 on your website, only in the fiddle, which made me think it had to do with the image not loading.

Comment: Hey ScottS, Thank You for taking the time to look and respond as well. In the passed hour several others and now you have told me they don't see the problem in firefox. The problem must be something local, I cleared my cache but that did not help.I've spent 2 days trying to fix this code and looks like all along nothing was wrong with it. .... wow ....